# the best sort 2D double arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, double

I'm currently trying to sort a 2D Array into ascending use selection sort. but the result is not good. 
i actually have a fairly large data like 
double array[1000][1000]
but if we example use data like this :

```
arrays = 10.555   1.023    5.852          
         8.856    1.001    4.483
         1.121    5.321    1.184
         5.123    0.834    3.151
         15.123   7.123    1.152
```

how to make a 2d array can be in sorting like this and can take on the index that has not previously sorting.
after array sorting :

```
arrays = 1.121   0.834   1.152   
         5.123   1.001   1.184
         8.856   1.023   3.151
         10.555  5.321   4.483
         15.123  7.123   5.852
```

and can save index like this in 2d array like this.

```
save_index = 2  3  4
             3  1  2
             1  0  3
             0  2  1
             4  4  0
```

i want this code can use in large dataset like double array[1000][1000]. what's the solution?

Comment: So you're trying to sort each column individually?  It'd be easiest to transpose the array (switch rows and columns) and use Java to sort for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like you want to sort each column separately, so the following answer is if my assumption is correct.
To solve something like this, I wouldn't use selection sort. I would use insertion sort, (because it's faster) and have a couple nested loops that will only go over certain columns. (For example, the first time the loop runs, have it only go through the first column and the second time it runs, have it only go through the second column).

Answer (score 0):

There are several sorting algorithms which are accepted in the literature. One of the fastest one is "Quick Sort" with its satisfying worst and average case performance. So you better to check it, instead of trying to implement a more effective algorithm. You can take a look at it [here](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort).